# Google Analytics 4 tag is not correctly implemented

Tags: analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm not exactly a developer but I've built a site on a WordPress platform and I'm trying to get the new Google Analytics GA4 working.
I installed the tags.
I asked Google support for information and this is the answer:
"Google Analytics 4 tag is still not correctly implemented".
Can anyone help me understand what I need to do to have a correct installation of the code?
Thank you
Roberto

Comment: Can you share the URL or piece of code that was implemented?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about web site management, not computer programming. In particular analytics are [an explicitly-listed topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for [webmasters.se].